# Full width split dropdown

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I am trying to do this by using Bootstrap-Vue, ¿any idea?.

```
Code & result:
```

[image]

It works fine in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpablogn/k2cx4m8h/1).

In my PC it works if I take out "scoped" from "style", ¿why?

Comment: Try to avoid using images when showing code as it can't be copy/pasted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't target a sub-component using a scoped style tag unless you use vue-loader and a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors).

Using a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

```
<style scoped>
  .especial, .especial ::v-deep button:first-child {
     width: 100%
  }
</style>
```

Or you can remove the `scoped` from your style tag

```
<style>
  .especial, .especial button:first-child {
     width: 100%
  }
</style>
```